# Calculate Discount Based on Total

Tags: cognito-forms

I’m new to Cognito Forms and am trying to give a discount once a Total is met. I have a FormTotal calculation field but it doesn’t seem to be calculating all the fields. I would like to Total the sections and base a discount off of that and then subtract that from the subtotal. Is it possible?

My FormTotal Calculation is `=SquareBales.ItemTotal+RoundBales.ItemTotal`.

And my discount one is: `=FormTotal >= 500 ? - FormTotal* 0.2 : 0`.

Any guidance is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the minus sign after the question mark, it's a syntax error.

```
=FormTotal >= 500 ? FormTotal * 0.2 : 0
```